# React.js. Ошибка POST запроса к функции Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, cors

Пытаюсь написать форму обратной связи в связке react.js - firebase.

Ошибка следующая:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://us-central1-react-feedback-form.cloudfunctions.net/' from origin 'https://react-feedback-form.firebaseapp.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Серверная часть

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require ('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.login;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.pass;

const app = express();

app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: false
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors);

app.post('/', (req, res) => {

 const output = `
  <p>You have a new contact request</p>
  <h3>Contact Details</h3>
  <ul>
   <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
   <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
   <li>Message: ${req.body.message}</li>
  </ul>
 `;

// Create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport

 var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
   user: process.env.EMAIL,
   pass: process.env.PASSWORD
  }
});

// setup email data with Unicode symbols

var mailOptions_new = {
 from: 'john.doe@mail.ru',
 to: process.env.EMAIL,
 subject: 'A new request frow web page!',
 html: output
};

var mailOptions = {
 to: req.body.email, // list of receivers
 subject: 'Thank you for contacting us!',
 html: 'We will acknowledge your request shortly.'
};

// Send mail with a defined transport object

transporter.sendMail( mailOptions_new, function (err, info) {
 if(err){
  console.log(err);
 } else {
  console.log(info);
 }
});

transporter.sendMail( mailOptions, function (err, info) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(info);
    }
})
res.status(200).end();
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Клиентская часть:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Form extends Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props );
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      message: ''
    };
    this.onSubmitHandler = this.onSubmitHandler.bind(this);
    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
    this.resetForm = this.resetForm.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let name = event.target.name;
    let value = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value /* The ES6 computed property name syntax is used to update the state key corresponding to the given input name: */
    });
  }

  onSubmitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const name = this.state.name;
    const email = this.state.email;
    const message = this.state.message;
    axios
    .post('https://us-central1-react-feedback-form.cloudfunctions.net/app', {
      data: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        message: message
      }
    })
    .then( ( res ) => {
      if ( res.data.msg === 'success' ) {
        this.resetForm();
      } 
    })
  }

  resetForm = () => {
    this.setState({
      name: '',
      email: '',
      message: ''
    });
  }

  render() {

    return(

        <form onSubmit = {this.onSubmitHandler}>
          <p>
            <label>Your name:
              <textarea id = 'name' type = 'text' name='name' required value = {this.state.name} onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
            </label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Your email:
              <textarea id = 'email' type = 'email' name='email' required value = {this.state.email} onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
            </label>
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Message:
              <textarea id = 'message' type = 'text' name='message' required value = {this.state.message} onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
            </label>
          </p>
          <div>
            <button type='submit' name='send'>Send</button>
          </div>
        </form>

    )
  }
}
```

Firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/app",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

CORS учтены в соответствии с документацией:
[Serve dynamic content and host microservices with Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions)

Пробовал

```
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  res.set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    if (req.method == "POST") {
     ... nodemailer code here
    }
})
```

и так

```
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: '*'});
```

Маякните, пожалуйста, в каком направлении копать.

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но по-моему проблема в редиректе. Судя по ошибке, при CORS-запросе происходит редирект, а редиректы для него запрещены. Я попробовал открыть ссылку и да, редирект на гугловую форму авторизации происходит.

Comment: @RTK проблема CORS оказалась слишком очевидной. Я по привычке передал в параметры транспорта auth: { user: process.env.EMAIL, pass: process.env.PASSWORD }, хотя д.б. gmailEmail и gmailPassword. А редиректы вроде и так закомментированы. Или я что-то путаю?

Comment: @RTK Проблема теперь в другом, я на сервере не могу получить данные из формы: req.body.email, req.body.name и req.body.message. Приходит undefined(((

Comment: И вдобавок не отрабатывает повторный вызов transporter.sendMail с параметром mailOptions (mailOptions_new срабатывает, но возвращает undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. По привычке вместо gmailEmail и gmailPassword в параметры транспорт nodemailer передал env.process.EMAIL и env.process.PASSWORD, плюс отсутствовали заголовки передаваемые axios, без которых body-parser отказывался воспринимать body:

```
headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
         }
```